# What is the difference between OpenSSL s_server and an http server?

Tags: openssl

The background for my question is that I am trying to get rid of an http/s server component from our code base, especially that our needs are very limited.  (we're not looking to support full fledged web browsing).

In order to not reinvent the wheel, I searched for an open source https server component of permissive license that is able to properly perform correct SSL termination. That's when I came across OpenSSL's s_server and s_client.

Can someone help me understand if the above s_server & s_client are enough as building blocks for an https server, assuming that all the right certs are in place?  A sample code or tutorial would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206861/146956) will do a good job of getting you up and running.

Basically the crux of the problem is passing either -HTTP or -WWW to your `openssl s_server` call:
`openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -WWW`

All -HTTP/-WWW do is serve "./" in response to GET requests:

```
 -WWW          - Respond to a 'GET /<path> HTTP/1.0' with file./<path> 
 -HTTP         - Respond to a 'GET /<path> HTTP/1.0' with file ./<path>
                  with the assumption it contains a complete HTTP response.
```

You're right, it can be used for a simple server.  This might be good enough to serve all you needs.

From the documentation the OpenSSL implementation doesn't seem to support these features, which you may miss:

- Returning a broad range of mime types
- Serving error codes other than 200/404
- State changes (POST etc. requests)
- Dynamic content (Although you could run cron or your own application in the background that updates the static files at certain intervals)